# Как в PowerShell прочитать свойство файла, если известно его имя?

Tags: powershell

Допустим на диске D: есть файл test.txt.
Проверить его наличие можно:

```
#устанавливаем месторасположение
Set-Location "d:\"
$a="test.txt"
#проверка на наличие файла
Test-Path $a
```

Но как теперь прочитать его свойства. Хотел так $a.name, но это не работает, потому что это строка, а не объект файла. Как получить не строку, а ссылку на файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте cmdlet `Get-Item`:

```
>$a="test.txt"
>$fileobject = Get-Item $a

>$fileobject.name
```